# SELECT comma separeted different values from single column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :
How to write SELECT, which show me on web page this result?
e.g MAMMALS: ELEPHANT, TIGER (with ',')

Table: Animals:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| ANIMAL_TYPE | ANIMAL_CODE | ANIMAL_NAME |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| MAMMALS     | 1           | ELEPHANT    |
| MAMMALS     | 2           | TIGER       |
| FISH        | 3           | CARP        |
| FISH        | 4           | SHARK       |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Table: Child

```
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| CHILD_NAME | ANIMAL_MAMMALS | ANIMAL_FISH |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
| ANNA       | 1,2            | 3           |
| WOJTEK     | 2              |             |
| DAWID      | 1              | 3,4         |
| ROBERT     |                | 4           |
+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

RESULT ON WEB PAGE:

`NAME: ANNA
MAMMALS: ELEPHANT, TIGER
FISH: CARP`

`NAME: ROBERT
MAMMALS: 
FISH: SHARK`

Comment: what you have tried so far, can you please post your code snippet.

Comment: This is really a bad DB design. Never store the comma separated values in DB. It violates the 1NF rule.

Comment: I know that this is bad DB design, but this is requirement for questionnaire

Comment: Comment does not compute.

Comment: Try using mysql group_concat function and group by ANIMAL_TYPE